# Как изменить роль после создания подключения к БД?

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

Нужно корректно реализовать метод, который позволяет задать пользователя при использовании ORM. Т.е. при выполнении запроса вызывать [`SET ROLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-role.html), [`SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-session-authorization.html), или [`EXECUTE AS`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql) в зависимости от БД.

Как правильно реализовать управление ролями в веб-приложениях при условии что в БД для каждого пользователя своя роль? Как после подключения к БД изменить пользователя для следующей транзакции?

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from dbviews import list_account_settings

engine = sa.create_engine('postgres://wepapp@localhost')

with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.execute('SET ROLE user12345')
    conn.transaction(list_account_settings)
    conn.execute('RESET ROLE')
```

Comment: Вы можете описать суть проблемы? Что именно не получается?

Comment: Изменить роль пользователя для подключения к БД после создания сессии при использовании ORM, не создавая нового подключения к базе. Цель - использовать права на строки/колонки прямо в БД. В примере выше - используется SQLAlchemy Core.